# In the past week I have been receiving the following message about delayed delivery of email

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook

I use Outlook with an EarthLink address, with Windows 8. I've been using this just fine until this week. What's going on?

This is an automatically generated Delivery Status Notification.

THIS IS A WARNING MESSAGE ONLY.

YOU DO NOT NEED TO RESEND YOUR MESSAGE.

Delivery to the following recipients has been delayed.

Comment: It means you or somebody with access to your account is sending email to an address that no longer exists.

Comment: In addition to the condition Ramhound describes, there could be other problems related to the destinating server.  The key point is that it doesn't indicate a problem at your end (unless every email you send produces that message regardless of who it is sent to).

Answer (score 1):

Delayed delivery means the mail server that is supposed to receive the e-mail is unavailable. It is possible the mail server no longer exists, but more likely it is unavailable due to server maintenance, network maintenance, etc. If the error keeps happening for the e-mail you are sending to, you should contact the domain owner of the recipient e-mail address. It is also common to receive this notice multiple times as your e-mail provider will repeatedly attempt sending the e-mail and will notify each time it was unable to. Eventually, if the delivery is not successfully, you will receive a final "Undeliverable" e-mail. This tells you the attempt was made and now the e-mail server is giving up. You have to send the e-mail again if you want to reattemp.